# How can i prevent a specific users from changing their passwords and allowing others to do it?

Tags: permissions, password, users

I'm trying to give some users the ability to change their password, and prevent some other specific users to do it. I already saw a question similar to this one but the solution was denying every user to change his own password.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'play' with the minimum age of a password
See `man 5 shadow`

```
sudo passwd -n <nb_days> username
# OR
sudo chage -m  <nb_days> username

# ex: sudo passwd -n 10000 johndoo
# will require a ~27 years age old password
# before allowing the user to change it
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested, but it doesn't deny these specific users from running the command "passwd"

Comment: @N_Craft : the user cannot change his password... That is what was asked.